# Probability of Forming a committee of 4 from nine men to always include a particular man.

Tags: probability

My Attempt: 9 nCr3. Would the fundamental counting theorem be used in this problem as one might consider that the particular man is being paired with the other 8 people?

Comment: wouldn't it be $8 \choose 3$ since you are pretty much seeing how many other people you can choose excluding particular man

Comment: I think the solution should be 9nCr3 * 9. The 9 comes from the fact that any nine people can be that particular person. Can you explain according to my thinking?

Comment: if you do 9 choose 3 you would be double counting because you include groups that would have the particular guy twice which can't happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To count the favourable ways, take the particular man out. Now choose $3$ from the remaining $8$, in $$\dbinom{8}{3}$$ ways. Since the possible ways are $\dbinom{9}{4}$ you have that the required probability is equal to $$\dfrac{\dbinom{8}{3}}{\dbinom{9}{4}}=\frac{8!4!5!}{3!5!9!}=\frac{4}{9}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let the 9 candidates be $\{1,2,3,\ldots,9\}$.

By symmetry, every candidate has the *same* probability to be in the committee. Let's call that probability $p$. (This is the expectation of a random variable whose value is always either 0 or 1, depending on whether Mr. 1 is on the committee or not. The *expectation* will be somewhere between those two possible values).

Since candidate $1$ has probability $p$ to be in the committee, the expectation of the *number* of elements of the set $\{1\}$ that are on the committee is $p$.

Likewise the expectation of the number of committee members in $\{2\}$ is $p$. And so forth.

The total number of members of the committee is (the number of committee members in $\{1\}$) plus (the number of committee members in $\{2\}$) plus ... up to (the number of committtee members in $\{9\}$).

Since expectations are additive, the *expected* number of members of the committee is $p+\cdots+p=9p$. But we *know* we're always selecting exactly 4 members, so $9p=4$. Therefore $p$ must be $4/9$.

(Look, no binomial coefficients!)